# Ubuntu Server LibreOffice Convert to txt Error

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, pdf

Running headless (only option since on server 14.04) trying to convert .doc files to .txt to be able to be ingested by php. Running the

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt test.doc
```

produces a test.txt file, with the contents like:

```
504b 0304 1400 0008 0000 0313 2247 9f03
2ec4 2b00 0000 2b00 0000 0800 0000 6d69
6d65 7479 7065 6170 706c 6963 6174 696f
6e2f 766e 642e 6f61 7369 732e 6f70 656e
...
0000 c1a3 0000 4d45 5441 2d49 4e46 2f6d
616e 6966 6573 742e 786d 6c50 4b05 0600
0000 000e 000e 0094 0300 0007 a500 0000
00
```

converting to .pdf works just fine.

Im guessing a library is missing... but unknown where to start. I did the straight install of libreoffice... `apt-get install libreoffice`

running the same files on mac with libreoffice works just fine, so I can rule out any originating file type issues.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Try adding an explicit filter i.e. `--convert-to txt:text`; otherwise, it seems to convert to "OpenDocument Text" which appears to be a zipped XML archive similar to Microsoft's .docx

Comment: What steeldriver said, but if I remember correctly `text` should be capitalized: `--convert-to txt:Text`. This did it for me once, when I had to convert some .doc files to plain text

Comment: Which Word-Version is the doc file?

Answer (score 0):

From the initial byte sequence `504b 0304` it's possible to deduce that the output is in the form of a `zip` archive.

In fact, a simple test with a minimal `.doc` file reveals that specifying `--convert-to txt` alone results in an OpenDocument Text file - but with a `.txt` extension:

```
:~$ soffice --headless --convert-to txt testdoc.doc
convert /home/steeldriver/testdoc.doc -> /home/steeldriver/testdoc.txt using 
Overwriting: /home/steeldriver/testdoc.txt

:~$ file testdoc.txt
testdoc.txt: OpenDocument Text

:~$ zipinfo testdoc.txt
Archive:  testdoc.txt
Zip file size: 8764 bytes, number of entries: 15
-rw----     2.0 fat       39 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 mimetype
-rw----     2.0 fat     1136 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 Thumbnails/thumbnail.png
-rw----     2.0 fat     4065 bl defN 15-Sep-02 15:58 content.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat     8849 bl defN 15-Sep-02 15:58 settings.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      894 bl defN 15-Sep-02 15:58 meta.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat    14890 bl defN 15-Sep-02 15:58 styles.xml
-rw----     2.0 fat      899 bl defN 15-Sep-02 15:58 manifest.rdf
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 Configurations2/toolpanel/
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 Configurations2/progressbar/
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 Configurations2/floater/
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 Configurations2/statusbar/
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 Configurations2/toolbar/
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 Configurations2/popupmenu/
-rw----     2.0 fat        0 b- stor 15-Sep-02 15:58 Configurations2/menubar/
-rw----     2.0 fat      978 bl defN 15-Sep-02 15:58 META-INF/manifest.xml
15 files, 31750 bytes uncompressed, 6938 bytes compressed:  78.1%
```

In order to force plain-text conversion, it's necessary to specify an *output filter* as well as an extension:

```
:~$ soffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text testdoc.doc
convert /home/steeldriver/testdoc.doc -> /home/steeldriver/testdoc.txt using Text
Overwriting: /home/steeldriver/testdoc.txt

:~$ file testdoc.txt
testdoc.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

Note this is still UTF-8 with a BOM: I haven't succeeded in finding a filter that produces plain ASCII. If you absolutely need ASCII there's always `iconv` e.g.

```
iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT testdoc.txt
```